# Xbim IFC Viewer ASP.NET

Tags: node.js, asp.net, cors, ifc, xbim

I successfully implemented an IFC viewer in NodeJs and am now trying to implement it in ASP.NET MVC Core 2.1

Here are my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>ASP.NET test IFC Viewer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/js/index.js"></script>
    <canvas id="aaa" style="height: 500px; width: 500px; border: solid 1px red;"></canvas>

    <script>
        var viewer = new Viewer('aaa');
        viewer.on('loaded', () => {
            viewer.show(ViewType.DEFAULT);
        });
        viewer.load('/model/SampleHouse.wexbim');
        viewer.start();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader();
                });
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In my root directory I execute from the command prompt:

`npm install @xbim/viewer`

I add the `index.js` file from the `node_modules` folder to the `wwwroot/js` folder

I then add a folder named `model` in `wwwroot` folder
In this folder I add the `SampleHouse.wexbim` file that I retrieved from the Xbim GitHub.

When I run my application and go to developer tools in network. I have a 404 error for the request `https://localhost:44365/model/SampleHouse.wexbim`

In the debugging tool I see this message below the 404 error:
`Failed to fetch binary data from server. Server code: 404. This might be due to CORS policy of your browser if you run this as a local file.`

[Message Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SarC3.png)

Do you know how to resolve the problem?

Maybe I'm not going about it the right way to integrate an IFC Viewer into an ASP.NET application and I need to use a completely different approach using C#. Don't hesitate to tell me.

- I tried to modify StartUp.cs to add CORS allowance.
- I tried to pay attention to the nomenclature of paths and file names.
- I tried to solve the problem with ChatGpt.
- I tried restarting my IIS Express server.
- I checked the access permissions to the wwwroot/model folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers are implementing the CORS requests for local files in a very strict manner - they should be requiring files to be from the same domain, but the spec says https so the implementation required http even if the entire domain is file based local files.

Here, I think you should access the files using http/https requests without using a local file (as I believe you might be loading the wexbim file directly in your js rather than accessing it via a remote call because it uses a relative path and not a http one).

But you can test this by editing your browser settings to allow such XHR permissions. On Firefox (screw Chrome) you set `[privacy.file_unique_origin][1]` to false in about:config. This ignores the security of loading files from a different origin (even if they are all local) and if your code starts working, then you know you are loading a local version and can fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to CORS restrictions on local files. To get around the problem I defined a custom root `/files/FILE_NAME` in the `Configure` method:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "files",
        template: "files/{fileName}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetFile" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

This configuration allows the application to recognize URLs containing `/files/FILE_NAME` as intended for special processing.

I've added a method to `HomeController.cs` that returns the contents of the file located in `wwwroot/model` to the client. :

```
public IActionResult GetFile(string fileName)
{
    // Chemin complet du fichier
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "model", fileName);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        // Lire le fichier et le retourner
        var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        return File(fileBytes, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```

The file can then be accessed via the `/files/FILE_NAME` root. I modified the Path in `index.cshtml` :

```
viewer.load('/files/SampleHouse.wexbim');
```

PS: I am on Mozilla. No need to set `privacy.file_unique_origin` to false.

Comment: Please change the German comment lines to English.

Comment: @gurkan Even translating the *French* comments would be useful. :)

Comment: @AdrianMole Looking back now, I don't understand why I wrote _German_ so precisely. Thus, it became clear how foreign I was to both languages :))  You are absolutely right 